# Moving pagination buttons in Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to move the pagination buttons/dots outside of the container div and into an outside div, so that I can have them positioned as shown below:

[image]

Things I've tried:

-upgrading to Owl Carousel 2. This basically destroyed the carousel and caused some very strange problems that I couldn't fix.

-moving them with jQuery. They did move but they vanished - they could be seen in the DOM when using inspect element, but didn't actually show up on the page at all.

Comment: Could you please provide your current HTML, CSS & any javascript affecting this so we can advise the changes you need to undertake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (if i understand you want dots to be on top right side)

```
.owl-pagination {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying position absolute in the pagination class or id and edit the top to position the pagination in your desire

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, give your container `position: relative`. Secondly, give your dots `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;`

That's all.